# SpringBoot Thymeleaf Not Resolving Template

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I'm using SpringBoot 1.3.3.RELEASE and Thymeleaf with IntelliJ as my ide. I'm getting this error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "footer.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (about:102)
```

I have this project layout:
[image]

I'm using this import on the about.html file:

```
<div th:replace="footer.html"></div>
```

I can't get it to work via IntelliJ or the SpringBoot Maven plugin. I'm using the embedded Tomcat to run this project. I've tried placing the fragment into a fragment folder under the templates and also this

```
<div th:fragment="footer.html"></div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your footer.html look like?
If you want to use a fragment you have to do it like that:

```
<div th:replace="footer :: fragmentName"></div>
```

Inside footer.html you would have something like

```
<div th:fragment="fragmentName">Hello World</div>
```